# How to implement cache synchronization in tomcat 6.0 cluster environment?

Tags: caching, messaging, tomcat6, cluster-computing

I'm currently working on a migration a web application to run in a cluster. This application uses caches. Some of this caches are reloaded in case the user saves something. I'ld like to inform the other nodes of the cluster about this, so that all nodes refresh their caches.

It seems that the tomcat server has a group messaging build in. (Tribes)
I'm wondering if I can use this messaging for my task and how to have the event listener run the whole day then.

with kind regards
   Michael

Comment: How is the cache currently implemented? EhCache? Or something hand-written?

Comment: The cache(s) are handwritten and use partly the servletcontext or the file system and also static fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use it and there is no need to start a thread or the like. 
Sending class instances around requires a jar of the message class in tomcat lib directory.

cheers
    Michae

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hazelcast Topic. It is a very lightweight pub/sub messaging. Each node will listen to the topic. When user saves smth on any node just put some message "REFRESH". On receive each node can do whatever you want. 
Here is the code to do this:

```
String REFRESH = "REFRESH";
ITopic<String> topic = Hazelcast.getTopic("myTopic");
topic.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<String>() {
        public void onMessage(String msg) {
          if(REFRESH.equals(msg){   
           //do refresh
          }
        }
    });
```

//when user saves sth.
  topic.publish(REFRESH);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using handwritten CACHE, Than you can synchronize cache B/W all nodes of cluster using message broadcasting/receiving , You can use `JGROUP` for that.

for ex: node A update cache that it just broad cast message to other node to refill(`refresh`) their cache